# Carbon X1 Gen 10 Lenovo not detecting monitor through usb - c connection?

Tags: thinkpad, external-monitor, usb-c

I have a new Lenovo machine----X1 gen 10 and its not detecting/displaying the external usb c monitor through the usb-c connection. (My pervious thinkpads T490 worked well in the same set up). Any ideas?

Comment: If you have Nvidia graphics than you need Nvidia drivers installed and working and Nvidia selected instead of the integrated GPU.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem here at my work. All new lenovo x1 gen10 received today won't display the picture at our 49” ultra wide monitor. But all ours x1 gen9 and x1 gen10 early 2022 works perfectly with the USB-c cable.

Comment: Welcome to AU. That doesn’t really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a simple fix.

Search for `display configuration` in the System settings.
There is the `device` dropdown select. Change it to an external device.
Check the `enabled` checkbox.
Turn the monitor off and on again

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what's the model of your monitor?
Because [this very same thing](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/10rn0zx/comment/jbjiz3h) is happening to me, but only with one LG model, and not other LG models. Tried Win11 and Ubuntu, same behavior in both cases.

In my case, and until there's a fix from either side (monitor or laptop), I'm using a dock station. USBC from laptop to dock, and DP from dock to monitor. More cables and one additional device in the table, but it allows me to share the screen and charge the laptop with a single USBC cable.

**EDIT** *(apr, 1st, 2023 - not a joke)*: Latest BIOS upgrade as of today from Lenovo solved this issue and the X1C-gen10 now happily works through USBC with the monitor.
BIOS version: Version 1.37 (UEFI BIOS), 1.18 (ECP)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Honest question: could you (is that a human beyond that script?) elaborate on what's missing in my answer? I mentioned my tests with other OSs as to discard it's a SW problem vs. a HW or firmware problem with the components. There's supporting information with a link to a post where I excplicitly mention the p/n of a working and a non-working monitor. And my solution explicitly mentions the connections types between the monitor, the dock, and the laptop.